# Batch paste to an api using post in R

Tags: r, api, post, httr, jsonlite

Im trying to paste multiple vin numbers to the nthsa API.

My working solution looks like this:

```
vins <- c('4JGCB5HE1CA138466','4JGCB5HE1CA138466','4JGCB5HE1CA138466','4JGCB5HE1CA138466','4JGCB5HE1CA138466','4JGCB5HE1CA138466','4JGCB5HE1CA138466','4JGCB5HE1CA138466','4JGCB5HE1CA138466','4JGCB5HE1CA138466','4JGCB5HE1CA138466',)

for (i in vins){

json  <- fromJSON(paste0('https://vpic.nhtsa.dot.gov/api/vehicles/DecodeVinValues/',i,'?format=json'))

print(json)


}
```

This solution is very slow. I tried pbapply, same thing because it pastes one vin at a time.

There is a batch paste option that i just cant figure out. Can someone please assist.

Here is my code so far:

```html
data <- list(data='4JGCB5HE1CA138466;4JGCB5HE1CA138466;4JGCB5HE1CA138466;4JGCB5HE1CA138466')

json <- toJSON(list(data=data), auto_unbox = TRUE)

result <- POST('https://vpic.nhtsa.dot.gov/api/vehicles/DecodeVINValuesBatch/', body = data)

Output <- content(result)
```

The vin numbers string has to be in the following format: vin;vin;vin;vin;

here is the link: https://vpic.nhtsa.dot.gov/api/    (the last one)

Thanks in advance.

UPDATE:

I also tried this from some other threads but no luck:

```
headers = c(
  `Content-Type` = 'application/json'
)

data = '[{"data":"4JGCB5HE1CA138466;4JGCB5HE1CA138466;4JGCB5HE1CA138466;4JGCB5HE1CA138466"}]'

httr::POST(url = 'https://vpic.nhtsa.dot.gov/api/vehicles/DecodeVINValuesBatch/', httr::add_headers(.headers=headers), body = data)
print(r$status_code)
```

I am getting status code 200 but server code 500 with no data.

Comment: Where do those JSON functions come from, `jsonlite`?

Comment: yes from jsonlite

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this is possible. The batch endpoint is specifically looking for a dictionary to be passed (ruling out string representations). `httr` states:

> body: must be NULL, FALSE, character, raw or list

I tried using `collections` library to generate dict

```
data <- Dict$new(list(format = 'json', data = "4JGCB5HE1CA138466;4JGCB5HE1CA138466;4JGCB5HE1CA138466"))
```

`httr` unsurprisingly rejected it as wrong body ype.

I tried using jsonlite to convert with:

```
data <- jsonlite::toJSON(data)
```

Yielding:

```
Error: No method asJSON S3 class: R6
```

I think due to data being an `environment`.

Trying to read in string dictionary to json returns `no data`:

```
library(httr)
library(jsonlite)

headers = c(
  'Accept' = '*/*',
  'Accept-Encoding' = 'gzip, deflate',
  'Content-Type' = 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
  'User-Agent' = 'Mozilla/5.0'
)

data = jsonlite::toJSON('{"format":"json","data":"4JGCB5HE1CA138466;4JGCB5HE1CA138466;4JGCB5HE1CA138466"}')

r<- httr::POST(url = 'https://vpic.nhtsa.dot.gov/api/vehicles/DecodeVINValuesBatch/', httr::add_headers(.headers=headers), body = data. encode='json'

print(content(r))
```

If we examine converted data

```
> data
["{\"format\":\"json\",\"data\":\"4JGCB5HE1CA138466;4JGCB5HE1CA138466;4JGCB5HE1CA138466\"}"]
```

This is no longer the dictionary structure the server expects.

So, I am new to R but seems like it might be easier to just go with Python which has a dictionary object and also a json library which handles comfortably the conversion

string to json:

```
import requests,json

url = 'https://vpic.nhtsa.dot.gov/api/vehicles/DecodeVINValuesBatch/'
data = json.loads('{"format": "json", "data":"4JGCB5HE1CA138466;4JGCB5HE1CA138466;4JGCB5HE1CA138466"}')
r = requests.post(url, data=data)
print(r.json())
```

dict

```
import requests

url = 'https://vpic.nhtsa.dot.gov/api/vehicles/DecodeVINValuesBatch/'
data = {'format': 'json', 'data':'4JGCB5HE1CA138466;4JGCB5HE1CA138466;4JGCB5HE1CA138466'}
r = requests.post(url, data=data).json()
print(r)
```

Comment: Thank you for trying but the call will be later used inside of the shiny app and I really need an R solution